# paperclip and rails 3.1 NoMethodError and nil object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, paperclip

I just updated Rails 3.0.10 to 3.1 and everything seems to be ok.

But Paperclip don't work anymore and give me an error :

> You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
>
> You might have expected an instance of Array.
>
> The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=

I'm unable to find the problem.. thank for help

**[edit after comment]**

Model :

```
class Community < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :commicon, :styles => { :thumb => "80x80>", :medium => "34x34!", :small => "20x20>", :rectangle => "80x40!", :mediumrect => "34x17>" , :smallrect => "20x10>"}
```

Controller:

```
class CommunitiesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @community = Community.find(params[:id])
```

View :

```
    <%= image_tag @community.commicon.url(:thumb) %>
```

I think nothing so special ?

Comment: Maybe you should post your code, it make more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem, thanks to the deprecated information of rails.

I updated my rails 3.1 to 3.2 and then it tell me that the plugins will be removed in the version 4.

After a quick look, I saw that I have a gem AND a plugin for paperclip and think my app was using the plugin.

Trashed the vendor folder and everything OK